# Asserting result of method within method in Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have a class like this which I need to unit test:

```
public class ClassA {
   private String methodA(String abc, String bcd) {
       ...
       //do some operation to get another String cde
       ...
       byte[] byteArray = methodB(cde)
       ...
       return def;
   }
   private byte[] methodB(String cde) {
       ...
       return byteArray;
   }
}
```

When I write the unit test for this class using Mockito, I can do this in the following manner:

```
public class ClassATest {
   @Mock ClassA classA;
   @Test
   void test() {
      String result = classA.methodA(abc, bcd);
      assertEquals(result, def);
   }
}
```

While this is fine, I also want to check the byte array returned by `methodB`. I can specify what the resultant byte array would look like in my `test()` method, but I am unsure of how to call `methodB` in `test()` and assert the output returned by it.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: "and assert the output returned by it" you can't, and should shouldn't care about the results of method calls inside another method. Test that `methodA` gives the expected result when you call it; test `methodB` directly if you need to.

Comment: You don't want to mock `ClassA`. For the code you've shown you don't need Mockito at all. You can't test `methodB` independently, it's part of the implementation of `ClassA`. If it needs to have its own tests (rather than being tested via calls to `methodA`), then create a new class and inject it into `ClassA`.